# How to create csv file in a specific folder with Python?

Tags: python, windows, csv, directory, permission-denied

I try to create multiple csv file with Python in a specific folder. But i got a "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"

```py
import csv
import os 

compteur = 0 
os.chmod(r'C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Exercices\concept\create_multiple_file', 436)
for i in range(20):
    compteur += 1
    filename = ("Pikachu{}".format(compteur))
    with open(r'C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Exercices\concept\create_multiple_file', "a") as folder:
        filewriter = csv.writer(filename, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        filewriter.writerow(['Name', 'Profession'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Derek', 'Software Developer'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Steve', 'Software Developer'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Paul', 'Manager'])
```

Comment: `filename = r'C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Exercices\concept\create_multiple_file\' + 'Pikachu{}'.format(compteur)`

Comment: Thx ! It worked for the denied permission. It creates a file but not in the right folder

Comment: Are you sure about that? Or are you looking at the file that was previously created by an earlier incorrect version of the same program?

Comment: I don't see the denied problem anymore. And yes the file is created is another folder. I tried a lot and read the "open" documentation but i don't find where i can write the folder where i put to put the file.

Comment: What is the desired output?  Show the folder structure you want and where the files should go.  From your answer it looks like `create_multiple_file` is a folder, which is why you can't write to it directly.  You need to write to a *file* not a *folder*.  It also looks like you want an additional folder named `folder` under the `create_multiple_file` folder.

Comment: You're right, i wanted to write where i want to put the created file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i can't find where to say "i want the created file in this specific folder", so i did it with Powershell. If someone wonder how to do it :

```
1..5 | foreach { new-item -path C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Exercices\concept\create_multiple_file\folder\Pikachu$_.csv }
```